# Error on create index for partitioned table Could not find any index named

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-partitioning

I'm trying to partitioning one table on my database, this particular table has more than 4 million records and I'm using the code bellow to create the partitionin by the datetime column IPE_DTL. Creating the partitioning dynamicaly. But when I try to create the index (just like the end of script ) its returning to me the following error:

> Could not find any index named 'IDX_cad_ipe_PartitionBy_DTL' for table 'cad_ipe'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pf_PartitionByMonthYear(DATE)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ();

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ps_PartitionByMonthYear
AS PARTITION pf_PartitionByMonthYear ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

CREATE TABLE #UniqueMonths (MonthYearValue INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #UniqueMonths (MonthYearValue)
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT, FORMAT(IPE_DTL, 'yyyyMM'))
FROM cad_ipe
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, FORMAT(IPE_DTL, 'yyyyMM'))

DECLARE @monthyear_value INT;
DECLARE @SqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @formatted_date_value NVARCHAR(8);

DECLARE monthyear_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT MonthYearValue FROM #UniqueMonths;

OPEN monthyear_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM monthyear_cursor INTO @monthyear_value;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    
    SET @formatted_date_value = CAST(@monthyear_value AS NVARCHAR(6));

    SET @SqlCmd = 'ALTER DATABASE Teste ADD FILEGROUP FG_cad_ipe_' + @formatted_date_value + ';';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCmd;

    SET @SqlCmd = '
        ALTER DATABASE Teste 
        ADD FILE (
            NAME = N''cad_ipe_data_' + @formatted_date_value + ''',
            FILENAME = N''B:\MSSQL\DATA\cad_ipe_data_' + @formatted_date_value + '.ndf'',
            SIZE = 5MB,
            MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
            FILEGROWTH = 5MB
        ) TO FILEGROUP FG_cad_ipe_' + @formatted_date_value + ';
    ';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCmd;

   SET @SqlCmd = 'ALTER PARTITION SCHEME ps_PartitionByMonthYear 
    NEXT USED FG_cad_ipe_' + @formatted_date_value + ';
    
    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pf_PartitionByMonthYear() 
    SPLIT RANGE (''' + @formatted_date_value + '01' + ''')';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCmd;

    FETCH NEXT FROM monthyear_cursor INTO @monthyear_value;
END;

CLOSE monthyear_cursor;
DEALLOCATE monthyear_cursor;

DROP TABLE #UniqueMonths;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_cad_ipe_PartitionBy_DTL] 
ON [cad_ipe] (IPE_DTL)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)
ON ps_PartitionByMonthYear(IPE_DTL);
```

I fixed the code to use the partition adding the following:

```
SET @SqlCmd = 'ALTER PARTITION SCHEME ps_PartitionByMonthYear 
    NEXT USED FG_cad_ipe_' + @formatted_date_value + ';
    
    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pf_PartitionByMonthYear() 
    SPLIT RANGE (''' + @formatted_date_value + '01' + ''')';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCmd;
```

but I'm still geting the error to create the custered index.

Comment: If this is a new index, remove `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to bother with a separate filegroups unless you have a specific reasons to do so, like piecemeal restore. Your script is not using the monthly filegroups and not creating the monthly partitions by splitting the partition function.

Comment: @DanGuzman hello, I already tryed remove the `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)` but it return the same error. I'm new with partitioning, so I'm having some troubles with it. The custered index its necessary to make the partition functional?

Comment: You will not get a "Could not find any index" if you actually removed the `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)` clause.  It seems you must have made a mistake if you still get the error.